# Overlclock raspberry pi some value missing

Tags: pi-2, overclocking

I would increase the raspberry performance, I found [this](https://haydenjames.io/raspberry-pi-3-overclock/) tutorial, that hint to add in `config.txt`:

```
arm_freq=1350
core_freq=500
over_voltage=4
disable_splash=1
#force_turbo=1 #Voids Warranty! (uncomment to avoid CPU scaling down to 600Mhz)
#boot_delay=1 #helps to avoid sdcard corruption when force_turbo is enabled.
#sdram_freq=500 #uncomment to test. Works only with some boards.
```

I noticed that the `core_freq` missing in my `config.txt` the same for `over_voltage`.

I need to add this value or something is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the **core_freq** and **over_voltage** option if they are not present (not all options are included by default).

You can read the latest on all of the [overclocking options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md), and the full documentation for the [config.txt file](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/) in the official Documentation.

**It is well documented, but worth mentioning that some values and options can void your warranty.**